# g Taglib reference inside an attribute of custom taglib is null

Tags: grails

I am trying to upgrade a grails 2.2.4 app over to grails 3.3.6 app and having issues with taglibs in the gsp.

Basically i have a gsp where in i am calling a taglib method inlined. This taglib method has attributes where i am invoking another taglib method which returns a value. THe snippet of the code in the gsp is as below.;

${g.message(code: 'some.code')}

The problem i am facing is that i am getting error saying "Cannot invoke method message() on null object". Here g is null. BTW this works in 2.2.4 application and is an issue with 3.3.6 version. I will appreciate any help towards identifying the cause of this issue.

THanks
Shiraz

Comment: Try to call without 'g', so just ${message(code: 'some.code')}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your line as

```
<g:message code="my.message.code" />
```

Check this document http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/message.html